# Method [where] does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have encountered a problem while working in `Laravel` project.

Method [where] does not exist. i know the '`Where`' clause is causing it .

I have studied it but not solution is found. finally i had to ask here.

```
$data = Track::where(
                [
                    ['generated_by', '=', Input::get('user_id')],
                    ['id', '=',Input::get('track_id') ],
                ])->get();


            $finalResult = array('code' => 100,
                'msg' => 'Your Account is found.',
                'data' => $data
                );
```

My controller name is `Track` . i have also made a Model named `Track` . the corresponding table name is `tracks` as `laravel` requires it to be plural of your model.

Can anybody please help me in this situation ?

Comment: Shouldn't ????::where be a model?

Comment: Is there a function inside of your controller called Track? and if so, then make sure to have `public` infront of the `function where`

Comment: If you have a controller called `Track`, and a model called `Track`, doesn't that cause confusion?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes it did cause the problem .I had to place \App\ in form of Track() . So that has indeed solved the problem.Thanks for the clue though .

Comment: I believe TrackController is a good name for your controller.

Comment: use aliasing to resolve the name collision like so: `use App\Model\Track as ModelTrack;` then do: `$data = ModelTrack::where(...`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solved.**
The problem was caused because i had same names of controller(Track) and my model (Track) .

I had to refer to model by useing \App\ in front of my model So my code would become

```
$data = \App\Track::where(
                [
                    ['genrated_by', '=', Input::get('user_id')],
                    ['id', '=',Input::get('track_id') ],
                ])->get();


            $finalResult = array('code' => 100,
                'msg' => 'Your Account is found.',
                'data' => $data
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have both a controller and model named `Track`.  And when you use `Track::where()` it assumes the where method is being called in your controller.

Unfortunately you can't just import your model as `Track` because then there would be a naming conflict.

You will need to alias your `Track` model.

In your import statements (`use`), add the following...

```
use App\Track as TrackModel;
```

This assumes your models are in the `App` namespace.  And modify your code...

```
TrackModel::where()...
```

That should get it working.  However I highly advise you to use proper naming conventions.  You will likely run into many more pitfalls going down this path that can easily be avoided.  Controllers should end in `Controller`.